# ExpressJS route regex

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I have route:

```
app.get('/:id', routes.action);
```

It works fine, but I need skip `robot.txt` and other (humans ....)
I create regex (only chars or number):

```
/^[a-z]{0,10}$/
```

How I can route only ids, which match this regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to avoid a route matching a static file that exists physically, simply put the `static` middleware before the call to the `app.router`.

Then the static file (such as robots.txt) will be delivered and these calls will not get through to your routing.

Problem solved ;-).

Answer (score 18):

Put the regex in parentheses like this:

```
app.get('/:id(^[a-z]{0,10}$)', routes.action);
```

Answer (score 2):

Internally, the strings that you give to the Express router are just converted into regexes anyway.  If you look at [the code](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/3.0.0rc3/lib/utils.js#L249-269), you can see that you can just pass a regex directly.

```
app.get(/^\/[a-z]{0,10}$/, routes.action);
```

[The docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB) also have examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for multiple routes :

```
app.routes.get
```

is an array having all of the get routes.
You can change the regex object for the routes you need to change.