# Match strings with extensions using app.param()

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

I've been building a simple site in Node.js to act as a proxy for Imgur images and albums for countries where it is blocked. Imgur URLs come in several types:

```
http://i.imgur.com/fiQ3A2t.jpg => Shows direct image
http://i.imgur.com/fiQ3A2t => Redirects to http://i.imgur.com/fiQ3A2t.jpg
http://imgur.com/fiQ3A2t => Loads gallery page
```

I am using Express.js, and what I'm trying to do it tell the difference between the URLs. The first URL needs no API call, however the other two do in order to get the direct image link. So far, this is what I'm using:

```
app.get('/:image', function(req, res){
  res.send('Requested image ' + req.params.image);
});
```

However, this matches everything (I just need everything after `.com/`. This means that if I enter a url like `mysite.com/fiQ3A2t.jpg` I have no way to distinguish between a direct link and a link requiring an Imgur API call.

To fix this, I've tried to use RegEx to match URLs with extensions and those without:

```
// Check for file extension
app.param('image', /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/gi);

app.get('/:image', function(req, res){
  res.send('Requested image ' + req.params.image);
});
```

However, this throws the following error when trying to run it:

```
Error: invalid param() call for image, got /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/gi
```

How can I go about handling `fiQ3A2t.jpg` different to `fiQ3A2t`? Ideally using Express's built in `.param` method but I'm open to everything. Just for context, the final site will be made so that you can replace `imgur` in any image links with `mydomain` and it displays the image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExpressJS route regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333845/expressjs-route-regex)

Comment: @cpancake using `app.get('/:image(\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/gi)')` as suggested results in `Cannot GET` error on every request.